# ¿Por qué la propiedad float con el valor left (o right) no hace que mi segundo "li" se muestre como debería?

Tags: html, css

Tengo este código HTML y CSS:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* BODY PARA EL COLOR DE FONDO Y DE TODAS LAS FUENTESS */
body{
    background: rgba(0,40,59,255);
    color: white;
}

body > header > nav > ul > li{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    list-style: none;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

img{
    width: 8em;
    border-radius: 15%;
}

/* body > header > nav > ul{
    margin: 0 20em;
} */

body > header > nav + nav > ul li{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo2.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="nmaslogo.png" alt="logotipo de n mas"></li>
                <li>Descubre</li>
                <li><a href="#">EN VIVO</a></li>
                <li><input type="search"></li>
                <li>Secciones</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Nacional</li>
                <li>Internacional</li>
                <li>Año Nuevo</li>
                <li>Salud</li>
                <li>Estado de México</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Me muestra el siguiente layout
[image: Preview de la imagen]

Quisiera, que el segundo ul (donde vienen los elementos li Nacional, Internacional, Año Nuevo, Salud, Estado de México) se muestre en línea como el elemento li de encima.

Lo que intenté:

Usé la propiedad clear con valor both para que omita los elementos flotantes de encima y se pase a una nueva línea. Ahí, usé la propiedad flotante con valor left para que actúen flotantes todos y les di un ancho del 20% (al ser 5 elementos deberían quedar justo).

Por qué no se muestra cómo quiero?

Answer (score 0):

```js
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* BODY PARA EL COLOR DE FONDO Y DE TODAS LAS FUENTESS */
body{
    background: rgba(0,40,59,255);
    color: white;
}

body > header > nav > ul > li{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    list-style: none;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

img{
    width: 8em;
    border-radius: 15%;
}

/* body > header > nav > ul{
    margin: 0 20em;
} */

body > header > nav > nav > ul li{
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo2.css">
    <title>Documsdsent</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><img src="nmaslogo.png" alt="logotipo de n mas"></li>
                <li>Descubre</li>
                <li><a href="#">EN VIVO</a></li>
                <li><input type="search"></li>
                <li>Secciones</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav>
            <ul id="test">
                <li>Nacional11</li>
                <li>Internacional</li>
                <li>Año Nuevo</li>
                <li>Salud</li>
                <li>Estado de México</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: me da error tu código, además no quiero usar ID's ni clases, quiero aprender sólo con flotantes. Gracias por comentar.